# Apache Shiro and Wildfly 8.1 JSESSIONID issue

Tags: shiro, jsessionid, wildfly-8

I have migrated Wildfly server from 8.0 final to 8.1 final and Apache Shiro started having problems when creating user sessions.

The exact same application runs without any problem on 8.0 final but with 8.1 users cannot establish sessions every time they log in they are redirected to the login page even though they were authenticated successfully.

I cannot figure out what has changed since 8.0 that would cause this issue.

Comment: You may want to post this question on the wildfly forums https://community.jboss.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the cookie name "JSESSIONID" to something else fixed the issue.

Here how I modified my shiro config

```
sessionManager=org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager=$sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled = true
cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie 
cookie.name = here.pick.your.session.id
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie
```